# Как вернуть несколько изображений Java

Tags: java, get, изображения, response

Пишу маленькое REST приложение. Есть метод в контроллере. С его помощью я могу вернуть только одно изображение из моей db. Как переписать его для возврата множества изображений?

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAll() {
        Img img = imgRepository.findById(2).orElse(null);
        byte[] imageFile = img.getImg();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        httpHeaders.setContentLength(imageFile.length);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(imageFile, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Эээ? А как вы хотите вернуть несколько картинок если браузер просил одну? Он очень удивится

Comment: @AlexeyTen  как предотвратить "удивление" браузера?

Comment: @user330092 Смотаться в W3C и попросить их изменить спецификацию протокола HTTP таким образом, чтобы он позволял в рамках одного запроса вернуть несколько файлов, после чего дождаться, когда это изменение начнут поддерживать браузеры и фреймворки. Ну или упаковать всё что вы хотите отдать в zip.